# phone gap - iOS keyboard click sound

Tags: ios, cordova

I've looked and looked but am surprised to find that I can't find a plugin or function to simply make a keyboard-click sounds via Phonegap. My use-case is that I've implemented a custom numeric keypad and I want to simply provide an audible 'click' when the user taps the buttons. 
Is it simply a case of using the media plugin and playing a sound? I kind of figured that a simple call to the OS would be easier.

Spent sometime looking at a custom plugin but I am new to PhoneGap so wanted to gather options.

Suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

dialogs plugin has the beep function

Install the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

Use the beep

```
navigator.notification.beep(1);
```

If you want to play the native keyboard input sound, you have to use this code on a custom plugin:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),     
^{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104);
});
```

or

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
```

list of other ids of sounds you can use

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

Comment: Thanks for the response. The beep function is somewhat strange on iOS and isn't the same as the normal OS keyboard 'click'.

Comment: beep is the only sound cordova provides. The normal OS keyboard 'click' is emited by the native keyboard click if the user has the sound active, see my edit to check how to play the keyboard input sound.

Comment: Great. Making progress with a plugin now. Will share when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

OK - taken quite sometime but done it..  Pretty convoluted for a newly PhoneGap / HTML guy.
As *jcesarmobile* pointed out - PhoneGap doesn't do this for you and navigator.notification.beep(1) isn't what I was after.

No option but to write a plugin.

**Learning number 1**: PhoneGap 3 has neat mechanism for installing plugins' saving you loads of time sticking the files in the right place in the project and adding the feature tags into the right config.xml. Not all the examples out on the net mention this.

**Learning number 2**: Projects without a Capital letter at the start of the name seem to cause an issue when adding plugins'. I was using 'phonegap plugins add xxxx' for ages but the .h and .m files were not being copied over as expected.

**Learning number 3**: plugman has a 'create' function that puts together a nice plugin template for you. I found this after making my own manually but there you go.

**Learning number 4**: The plugman template set's the target to "cordova.plugins.xxx" so don't forget to use that to call you native function from your Javascript (i.e. cordova.plugins.yourMethod)

**Note 1**: plugman creates an example with a single method (coolMethod). You'll need to change that (obviously). Also - it has a single .m file rather than the more typical .h and .m files.

Sure there were more hurdles along the way but can't recall them now.

In the end the native code was really easy. I'd already used the 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSound' call in a swift project a while back so the native bit was much easier for me than the rest.

Code is below. You'll notice that I only return a successful result and do away with all the parameter handling.

- (void)clickSound:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
  {
  CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                 ^{
                     AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450);
  });
  pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"done"];
  [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];

}

@end